# Ways to show MessageBox from other classes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, messagebox

I want show my app user with a MessageBox based on some activity happened in that class. I was just wondering what could be the best way to do so. One way that I know doesn't seem to be the ideal one.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(MessageString, TitleString, MessageBoxButton.OK);
});
```

Comment: What about IoC (Dependency Injection)? You can prepare `INotificationService` that shares method `NotifyUser(string msg, string title)` (and other overloads), implement it (with your code) and pass instance via construtor to any class that you want to?

Comment: `MessageBox` is not ideal mechanism to notify user about something. You should use some other kind that does not require user to click a button for each message to be received. Maybe some status line that can be expanded to several lines.

Comment: @Dialecticus It doesn't happen on user click. I have some other code logic to decide in that class based on which I want to trigger this.

Comment: @pwas I am new to this. Can you please suggest some link or tutorial for getting started with this IoC. I tried goggling it, but didn't land up on a helpful link. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try a toast notification

```
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
toast.Title = "[title]";
toast.Content = "[content]";
toast.Show();
```

Comment: You can't use a ShellToast while the app is the foreground app. It's meant to be invoked from a background service while the app isn't the foreground app.

Comment: On devices with Windows Phone 8 Update 3, toast notifications are displayed when the target app is running in the foreground but is obscured by other activity such as a phone call or the lock screen.